# Wizzair Discount Club, add multiple passengers

Tags: wizz-air

So I just bought WDC and wanted to book a flight for me and my friend, but it always adds my name as it's mandatory for the booking with WDC. I can't find where I can add another passenger to the same booking. How can I book a flight for 2 people using WDC?